# Sharepoint REST API calls returning 404 not found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

We are trying to access SharePoint REST APIs, each call to them returns with 404 NOT Found error. We tried to check `https://sitename/_api/contextInfo`, there was again 404 error in response.

We are trying to access this API from an IOS app. Tried the same from POSTMAN to confirm the same.

Kindly advice.

Comment: Which HTTP method u are using? You need to use HTTP POST

Comment: POST Method @AtishDipongkor

Comment: Just to be sure, is this SP 2013?  2010 has a different REST syntax.

Comment: its 2010. Could you please let me know the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The correct one is `https://sitename/_api/web`. If you type this URL in a browser like Chrome, it should display the current site information in XML.

**Also check your protocol, it might be https instead of http.**

If you still get the error than you need to download the `SP 2013 Client Components SDK` & brought up `PowerShell V3`

Use below mentioned code in `PowerShell V3`

```
# Invoke-RestSPO -Url "https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/_api/web"
```

Above code came from below mentioned code

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Sends an HTTP or HTTPS request to a SharePoint Online REST-compliant web service.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function sends an HTTP or HTTPS request to a Representational State
    Transfer (REST)-compliant ("RESTful") SharePoint Online web service.
.EXAMPLE
   Invoke-SPORestMethod -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web"
.EXAMPLE
   Invoke-SPORestMethod -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo" -Method "Post"
#>
```

Comment: We tried using this but still it gives 404 not found. I tried in browser and POSTMAN also.